# Is there a better way to track pagination with hashtags?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pagination

Using a hashchange event I'm detecting when a user clicks the back button in a browser and changing the URL accordingly.  Is there a better way to do this for pagination?  I'm currently changing the URL after a user clicks my pagination control like so:

```
$(".pager").click(function(){

    var start = null;
    if ($.browser.msie) {    
        start = $(this).attr('href').slice($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#')+1);
    } 
    else {    
        start = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
    }

    $('#start').val(start);

    $.post("visits_results.php", $("#profile_form_id").serialize(),
    function(data) {
        $('#search_results').html(data);
        location.href = "#visits=" + start; 
    }); 

    return false;
});
```

My javascript to detect the back button looks like this:

```
function myHashChangeCallback(hash) {

    if (hash == "") {
        $("#loadImage").show();

        var no_cache = new Date().getTime();
        $('#main').load("home.php?cache=" + no_cache, function () { 
        $("#loadImage").hide();
    });

    return false;

    }
    else {
    // adding code to parse the hash URL and see what page I'm on...is there a better way?; 
    }
}

function hashCheck() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash != _hash) {
        _hash = hash;
        myHashChangeCallback(hash);
    }
}
```

I currently plan on checking each hashtag and the value to see what page I should load unless there is a better more efficient way.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) plugin does this very well. Once setup it provides a series of logical navigation events which you can hook into. It also has very good support for `history.pushState()` which eliminates the need for hashtags in newer browsers and has equally good fallback support for those browsers that do not support pushState.

A simple implementation would look like this:

```
// Run some code on initial load
$.address.init(function(e) {
    // Address and path details can be found in the event object
    console.log(e);
});

// Handle hashtag/pushState change events
$.address.change(function(e) {
    // Do more fancy stuff. Don't forget about the event object.
    console.log(e);
});

// Setup jQuery address on some elements
$('a').address();
```

To enable pushState() support pass an argument to the script like so:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.address-1.3.min.js?state=/absolute/path/to/your/application"></script>`

Comment: I've looked at this but it seems a bit difficult to implement. I'm worried I'll need to replace all my current javascript code...but I may have to.

Comment: The examples on the site are horrible, actually. Take a look at the source code on [this page](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/). You only really need to call three methods. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: My pleasure. Let me know if you run into any trouble with it.

Comment: Looks like it's doing what I need.  I'm still using location.href = "#visits=" + start; to set my URLs with an onclick event and the address.change method is picking everything up!  Thanks again for the help and examples!